# ImGui C++ отсутствует математический оператор "+"

Tags: c++, imgui

Пытаюсь сделать свой элемент для ImGui. Как говорил разработчик, не стал редактировать оригинальный файл imgui.cpp, а вношу изменения в отдельном файле. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка - `отсутствует оператор "+", соответствующий этим операндам`
В оригинальном файле ImVec2 + и - ImVec2 работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте вот так:

```
#include <imgui.h>
#ifndef IMGUI_DEFINE_MATH_OPERATORS
#define IMGUI_DEFINE_MATH_OPERATORS
#endif
#include <imgui_internal.h>
```

Код взял из `imgui.cpp`, но заменил кавычки на треугольные скобки.